# Ruby like ranges in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, range

In ruby you can specify a range like:

```
(1...10).each do |num|
  puts num
end
```

or

```
(1...15).each do |num|
  puts num
end
```

is there a way to do something similar in JS ***without*** having to build a function that defines a range, such as:

```
function myRange() {
  let x = [1,2,3];
  return x;
}
```

*Also the question on stack overflow "Does JavaScript have a method like “range()” to generate a range within the supplied bounds?" is the opposite of this question.*

***without*** <- keyword

Comment: You can create an array like this: `Array.from({length: 15}, (_, index) => index + 1)`, then `.forEach((value) => console.log(value))`.

Comment: @Xufox I saw that question but it is the opposite of my question. Its asking for a function.

Comment: I’m not sure why you wouldn’t want a function. Why does that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems like your question is specifically whether there is an built-in method to do this and you don't accept any workarounds, the answer is no, there is no built-in js method to do this.